# What ip6 address do I share so my friends can connect to it?

Tags: networking

Is the second ip6 address the correct one to share? It doesn't look right.

So I am a linux person. I type ipconfig in my termial and I get:

```
eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
         inet 192.168.0.147  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
         inet6 fe80::9cba:b6b7:f642:4449  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
         inet6 2601:400:4300:743:86a8:500:ec4e:b726  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
         ether 18:03:73:cb:bd:91  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
         RX packets 305129  bytes 31901328 (30.4 MiB)
         RX errors 0  dropped 9041  overruns 0  frame 0
         TX packets 404299  bytes 545769431 (520.4 MiB)
         TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
         device interrupt 20  memory 0xe1a00000-e1a20000
```

I tried going to both inet6 addresses on my phone that I am not connected to the WiFi.

I went to this address and put in the 192.168.0.147 address and it prints out another ip6 address.

https://dnschecker.org/ipv4-to-ipv6.php

Comment: aside from my answer [this](https://test-ipv6.com) is a decent way to check ipv6 connectivity

Comment: What makes it "not look right"?

Answer (score 1):

> inet6 fe80::9cba:b6b7:f642:4449  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20

This is your local IP address - see the scope ID, and local IPs always start with fe80

> inet6 2601:400:4300:743:86a8:500:ec4e:b726  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0

This should be it - see the scope. You can also run the whois command on it and see if it belongs to the same ISP you use